Discord Webhook issue
I want to send messages through discord webhooks with the MQ5 language. I encounter the server response:

Cannot send an empty message (Code: 50006).

I've been stuck here for a while now.
void SendDiscordMessage(const string message) {
    string data = "{\"username\":\"Webhook\", \"avatar_url\":\"https://i.imgur.com/4M34hi2.png\", \"content\":\"" + message + "\"}";
    Print("Extended JSON data being sent: ", data);

    uchar postData[]; 
    ArrayResize(postData, StringLen(data) + 1); 

    char result[]; 
    ArrayResize(result, 1024);
    string responseHeaders;
    int dataSize;

    dataSize = StringToCharArray(data, postData);

    string headers = "Content-Type: application/json\r\n";

    int res = WebRequest("POST", Webhook_URL, headers, "", 5000, postData, dataSize, result, responseHeaders);
    if (res == -1) {
        Print("Error sending message: ", GetLastError());
    } else {
        Print("Message sent successfully. Server response: ", CharArrayToString(result));
    }
}

int StringToCharArray(const string& str, uchar& buf[]) {
    int len = StringLen(str);
    for(int i = 0; i < len; ++i) {
        buf[i] = str[i];
    }
    buf[len] = '\0';
    return len + 1;
}

